# Multiple authentication controllers on one route

Tags: node.js, authentication, express, passport.js, basic-authentication

I am trying to add two authentication controllers to one route. For example, this is basically what I am trying to make:

```
router.route('/employees')
      .get(authController1.isAuthenticated, myController1.get1)
      .get(authController2.isAuthenticated, myController2.get2);
```

The isAuthenticated function is as follows:

```
exports.isAuthenticated = passport.authenticate('basic', {
  session: false
});
```

Does anyone know how this would be possible?

Thanks,
Daniel

Comment: You cant have two GET methods for the same endpoint? If you want to add two authentication methods comma separate them like this.  `.get(authController1.isAuthenticated, authController2.isAuthenticated , myController1.get1)`

Comment: @RichardMacarthy I was just trying to express the functionality. Thank you but how would I be able to distinguish which authController was responsible for calling .get1?

Comment: See my answer, will this work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Route:

```
router.route('/employees')
      .get(authController.isAuthenticated1, authController.isAuthenticated2, myController1.get1)
```

authController :

```
exports.isAuthenticated = function(req, res, next) {
    // Authentication code
    if (!req.isAuthenticated) {
        // Not authenticated
        return res.status(401).send({
            message: 'User is not authenticated'
        });
    }
    next();
};

exports.isAuthenticated2 = function(req, res, next) {
    // Authentication2 code
    if (!req.isAuthenticated2) {
        // Not authenticated
        return res.status(401).send({
            message: 'User is not authenticated'
        });
    }
    next();
};
```

myController

```
exports.get1 = function(req, res) {
    // Both are authenticated so we can proceed.
}
```

Comment: Hmm, thank you again but not quite what I need. I need to be able to determine which authenticator lead to the 'get1' function. Two types of users (hence the two auths) and depending on what type of user I need to execute different functionality. Which is why I initially had .get1 and .get2. I could use just .get1 if I could identify which type of user it is in it.

Comment: Maybe like the new answer?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this?

```
exports.isAuthenticated = function(req, res, next) {
    req.user == 'type1' ? fnType1(req, res, next) : fnType2(req, res, next); // Do check and call method.
};

function fnType1(req, res, next) {
    //Authentication code
    // Attach type to req
    req.userType = 1;
    next();
}

function fnType2(req, res, next) {
    //Authentication code
    // Attach type to req
    req.userType = 2;
    next();
}

exports.get1 = function(req, res) {
    // Both are authenticated so we can proceed.
    if(req.userType = 1){
        // Do something
    } else {
        // Do something else
    }
}
```

Comment: Mmm, no not quite. The two isAuthenticated methods I believe must remain separate as it does use two different models for each 'type' of user.  So depending on which authController returns true a specific function must be called (or one function with some way to tell which authController called it).